# laravel eloquent relationship for indirectly related model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I want a relationship where two unrelated models are linked together with a linker model.

My tables are like:

`card` table

```
id(pk)
name
```

`User` table

```
id(pk)
username
password
card_id(fk)
```

`Feature` table

```
id(pk)
name
card_id(fk)
```

How can i define an eloquent relationship to access all the features of user's card from user model like this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function features(){
        return $this->relatonship_statement;
    }
}
```

and when I tried in Card Model:

```
class Card extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function features(){
        return $this->hasMany(Feature::class);
    }
}
```

and in User model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function card(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function features(){
        return $this->card->features;
    }
}
```

I get error:

`App\Models\User::features must return a relationship instance.`

Comment: `public function features(){
        return $this->card->features;
    }` <<< ^^^ there's your error, that returns a collection

Comment: Yes. But how to make it return relationship instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want is an accessor function, not a relationship. This is how you would do to achieve what you want.

```
class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $appends = ['features']; //to append features in the response json

    public function card(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Card::class); //editted User to Card
    }
    public function getFeatures(){ //accessor method
        return $this->card->features()->get();
    }
}
```

sample result after returning user in a controller function

```
return User::query()->with('card')->first();
```

[image]

However, the right way is to access the features through the Card Relationship because these two models have a direct relationship.